# VSCode won't install extension - Permission denied

Tags: visual-studio-code, macos-catalina

I am having a problem installing extensions on VSCode on macOS Catalina. In console says permission denied. When I checked permission, I have read and write permission and still won't install.

I couldn't find the respective solution to the error so eventually posting here and seeking help to fix the issue.

### Error Message

> extensionsActions.ts:265 Error: Unable to write file
> '/Users/me/Library/Application
> Support/Code/CachedExtensionVSIXs/shan.code-settings-sync-3.4.3'
> (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied,
> open '/Users/me/Library/Application
> Support/Code/CachedExtensionVSIXs/shan.code-settings-sync-3.4.3')

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the issue was permission. Fixed by change ownership of the folder `CachedExtensionVSIXs`

### User this command to fix it

```
sudo chown -R ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/CachedExtensionVSIXs
```

Or lead to the Code folder `~/Library/Application\ Support/Code` and run the below command

```
sudo chown -R CachedExtensionVSIXs
```